# scp with special username

Tags: linux, shell, scp

I'm trying to create a `shell` script for copying files to a remote backup.

This is my script so far:

```
PASSWORD=MY-SECRET-PASS
URL=SLOS755513-3:SL1255513@objectstorage.net
DIR=/backup

scp /home/user/my_log.txt $URL:$DIR
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname SLOS755513-3: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

I guess it's because of the special characters in the username, because if I simply write `test` instead it actually tries to connect with `test` as user.

But I've tried to escape `\-` and `\:` and everything gives me the same error.
I'm also unsure how to use the password in the script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RUSER='SLOS755513-3:SL1255513'
HOST=objectstorage.net
DIR=/backup

scp -o user=$RUSER /home/user/my_log.txt $HOST:$DIR
```

This will make the user part explicit so `scp` doesn't try to interpret `:` as host/path separator. `-o user=$USER` will send the user as an option to the underlying `ssh`.

Comment: Running that doesn't change user apparently. It asks for `$ ./upload.sh
user@objectstorage.net's password:`, and not `$ ./upload.sh
SLOS755513-3:SL1255513@objectstorage.net's password:`

Comment: Sorry `-o user=...` had to come before the filepath, my mistake. It works. Thank you.